# Editing inserting values in YAML based on criteria using a bash script

Tags: bash, yaml

A YAML file as follows:

```
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  - job_name: 'node-exporter'
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: instance
        regex: '([^:]+)(:[0-9]+)?'
        replacement: '${1}'
    static_configs:
      - labels:
          type: 'YYY'
          group: 'Bar'
        targets:
        - '192.168.1.134:80'
        - '192.168.1.146:80'

      - labels:
          type: 'YYY'
          group: 'Foo'
        targets:
        - '192.168.2.136:80'

      - labels:
          type: 'ZZZ'
          group: 'Foo'
        targets:
        - '192.168.2.100:80'
```

I'd like to use a bash script to add the "targets" to the YAML based on "type" and "group". For example:

```
./add_host.sh 192.168.1.17:80 YYY Bar
```

Added bonus for deleting entries :)

Things I've tried (and failed):
Using [jq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq);
Tried using `sed` to insert values, but I have trouble in finding the right section to insert it to (Block parsing).

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mean that you want to parse the YAML file with bash, do you?  That would be tedious and error-prone, not to mention slow to execute.  You must mean you want a command-line utility to manipulate the file.

What you want is something that parses the YAML into a data structure.  If I were doing it, I'd try the Python [PyYAML](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) module. It represents the whole file as a nested data structure.  Read it in, change the parts you want to change, and write it out.